# ArcPy inconsistently accepts SQL queries for MakeFeatureLayer or SelectLayerByAttribute

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, feature-layer, error-000358, error-000230

I need to buffer a subset of features in a particular feature class. To do this, I am first creating a feature layer (using a SQL query to select only what I want), and then running Buffer. So my ArcPy script includes this little function to buffer my handful of feature classes:

```
def funcBuffer(inFeature, outFeature, bufDist, querySQL):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeature, "tempLayer", querySQL)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("tempLayer", outFeature, bufDist, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

This works perfectly on *most* of my feature classes. However, there is one that fails. The Python error is:
`ERROR 000230: Failed selecting with "OH_UG" = 'UG'`

The [help page for that error](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000005000230.htm) suggests that the SQL query is invalid. However,

- the field `OH_UG` exists, and there are some features with the value "UG"
- it successfully validates in Query Builder
- I can use it to Select by Attribute with no problem (python snippet from within ArcMap: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("TransmissionLines","NEW_SELECTION","OH_UG = 'UG'")`)
- similarly structured queries work on other feature classes

I've tried different ways of passing the SQL query and all fail: `'"OH_UH" = \'UG\''`, `'OH_UH = \'UG\''`, `""" "OH_UG" = 'UG' """`

I revised the script to do the selection after making the feature layer:

```
def funcBuffer(inFeature, outFeature, bufDist, querySQL):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeature, "tempLayer")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tempLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", querySQL)
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis("tempLayer", outFeature, bufDist, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
```

and now `MakeFeatureLayer` works, but `SelectLayerByAttribute` throws `ERROR 000358: Invalid expression` -- still a complaint regarding invalid SQL.

I attempted to select using a different (numeric) field in the table, and am still getting the same `000358` error.

---

So I am not sure what's going wrong -- is it the SQL, is it the particular feature class, is it gremlins? How can I work around the problem in ArcPy?

Comment: Background server threw an exception usually means the tool caused a crash. Just curious, if you disable BG and run the same tool /w same settings, does ArcMap crash?

Comment: Have you tried running the select analysis tool in ArcMap and exporting the result as a python snippet. Generally I don't recommend using the export but it may give insight to how it passes the SQL query and you may be able to copy it.

Comment: @KHibma -- I just turned off background processing to check, and it successfully ran. (Which I don't think is necessarily because of the tool running in the background, there's probably something else contributing [Arc got rebooted between the `00143 error` and now])...

Comment: @ChrisR It's sending it within triple quotes: `arcpy.Select_analysis("TransmissionLines","C:/temp/scratch.shp",""""OH_UG" = 'UG'""")`

Comment: Are all the feature classes you are testing coming from the same geodatabase?

Comment: @papadoo They're from a variety of different geodatabases on an SDE server. The "broken" one is the only one I'm pulling from its geodatabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After over a week of attempting to debug this, a colleague used it on his computer.... and it consistently worked fine.

Turns out his SDE connection had different permissions and the feature in question was in a database which was restricted to read-only for me, but not for him. When we copied that SDE connection to my machine, I could run the script without problems.

*Why* exactly this would cause a problem, I am still not sure. There are no geoprocessing tools trying to act on the original data, it just makes a copy -- but changing that solved the problem.