# arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management: query throws error 000230/000358

Tags: arcpy, query, feature-layer, error-000358, error-000230

Im trying to create a feature layer on which i want to perform a select by location, however:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (perp, "selected","LINK_ID = 23002109")
```

throws:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000230: Failed selecting with LINK_ID = 23002109
```

and

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (perp, "selected")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("selected", "NEW_SELECTION", "LINK_ID = 23002109")
```

throws:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
```

The same query works fine when done manually in ArcMap. The field exists and its datatype is DOUBLE.

My problem seems to be exactly the same as in [ArcPy inconsistently accepts SQL queries for MakeFeatureLayer or SelectLayerByAttribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112039) The difference is I'm working with a local GDB and not with a SDE connection. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build SQL queries that will always work no matter input use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> Adds field delimiters to a field name to allow for use in SQL
>   expressions.
>
> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

, [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output.

And Three double quotes to build your query.
Like this:

```
import arcpy
feature_class = r'C:\test.gdb\polygons'    
query = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature_class,'LINK_ID'), 23002109)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature_class, 'polygon_lyr',query)
```

This query will also work in Select By Attributes

Comment: Strange now I'm getting: module 'object' has no attribute 'addFieldDelimiters'. I'm using 10.2.2 shouldn't that be a default feature?

Comment: Yes: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000091000000

Comment: Should be cap A, not a